# Redirect short/host name to subdomain

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, haproxy

I have a collection of hosts that currently use just hostnames for reference, I'm switching over to using haproxy as an https proxy and would like to do a rewrite or redirect from `http://server1/` to `https://server1.internal.mydomain.com/`.

```
# do a redirect for insecure connections
http-request redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
```

I have the HTTPS redirect/upgrade working as expected it's getting the rewrite/redirect configured properly that I'm hung up on, and I'm not really sure on the right verbiage to use when asking the question to get a relevant answer.

```
defaults
        mode http
        timeout client 10s
        timeout connect 5s
        timeout server 10s
        timeout http-request 10s

frontend mydomain_frontend
        # Listen for both http and https requests
        bind *:80
        bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/Wildcard_mydomain_web_server.pem
        # Setup conditional ACLs for hosts
        acl server1_hosts hdr_beg(host) -i server1. server1 server1-2. server1-2
        acl server2_hosts hdr_beg(host) -i server2. server2 server2-2. server2-2
        
        # Setup Conditional ACLs for redirecting short/host names to FQDNs
        acl is_internal hdr_sub(host) -i internal.mydomain.com
        # I think the ACL is right, I'm just not sure how I would do the redirect, Is there string substitution?
        http_request redirect location https://ORIGINALHOST.internal.mydomain.com if !is_internal

        # do a redirect for insecure connections
        http-request redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
        use_backend server1_bend if server1_hosts
        use_backend server2_bend if server2_hosts
        default_backend server1_bend

# Setup DNS resolution
resolvers default
        nameserver ns1 10.10.10.1:53
        nameserver ns2 10.10.10.15:53

backend server1_bend
        mode http
        option forwardfor if-none
        # server site 11.11.11.11:80 check resolvers default
        server site server1.internal.mydomain.com:80 check resolvers default

backend server2_bend
        mode http
        option forwardfor if-none
        # server site 10.10.10.10:80 check resolvers default
        server site server2.internal.mydomain.com:80 check resolvers default
```

** EDIT **
I added an acl and a partial redirect statement to my example configuration, I think it is the beginning of what I am looking for but I don't know if it will work without string substitution in the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the http-request line to use `hdr(host)` and `pathq` solved the issue for me.

```
http-request redirect location https://%[hdr(host)].internal.mydomain.com%[pathq] if !is_internal
```

`hdr(host)` - is the host from the URI minus the path and queries.

`pathq` - is the path including any queries. if we wanted just the path we could use just `path`.

The `%[]` pattern is important for triggering the substitution.